# how to fix this Zabbix alert template to work?

Tags: zabbix

Zabbix Version: 4.0 LTS

```
# template

Alert: {EVENT.NAME}
Severity: {EVENT.SEVERITY}

Top cpu:
{HOST.NAME:sys.process.top.cpu.last()}

Top mem:
{HOST.NAME:sys.process.top.mem.last()}

Problem started at {EVENT.TIME} on {EVENT.DATE}
```

Render result:

```
Alert: test top usage
Severity: Disaster

Top cpu:
*UNKNOWN*

Top mem:
*UNKNOWN*

Problem started at 03:35:00 on 2020.05.29
```

How to fix it to normal? I hope it could get the value of the current host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should use the {{HOST.HOST}:sys.process.top.cpu.last()} to work.

More information could refer to this online document.

https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=xgjVDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA333&lpg=PA333&dq=zabbix+%7B%7BHOST.NAME%7D%7D:key.last()%7D&source=bl&ots=zQHgguJ0hm&sig=ACfU3U3-FOGUIJjtJSvpoC_l5YXpx6l7fQ&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&redir_esc=y&sourceid=cndr#v=onepage&q=zabbix%20%7B%7BHOST.NAME%7D%7D%3Akey.last()%7D&f=false

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{ITEM.VALUE<1-9>}` macro, as described in 
 [macros/supported_by_location](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location).

Functions, like `last()`, are not supported in alerts.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Iron Bishop. I have found a solution to this question.